# using @expo-google-app-auth giving me error

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo, google-signin

I used LogInAsync function from @expo-google-app-auth package. It works until it opens browser window. In browser window, It is throwing 400: Invalid_request error. Someone's help would be highly appreciated.

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nMgA.jpg)

[Code on GitHub](https://github.com/hitenvats16/Day-Diary/blob/main/screens/login.js)

Code for those who live in hurry..

`import { TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";`
`import { AntDesign } from "@expo/vector-icons";`
`import * as Google from "expo-google-app-auth";`

`export default function SignIn() {`
`const LogInHandler = async () => {`
`const { type, accessToken, user } = await Google.logInAsync({`
`androidClientId: "ClientId_From_GoogleCloud",`
`androidStandaloneAppClientId: "ClientId_From_GoogleCloud",`
`});`
`if (type === "success") {`
`let userInfoResponse = await fetch(`
`"https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me",`
 `{`
`headers: { Authorization:` Bearer ${accessToken} `},`
`}`
 `);`
 `console.log(userInfoResponse);`
`}`
`};`

 `return (`
`<View style={styles.container}>`
`<Text style={styles.header}>Signing Options</Text>`
`<TouchableOpacity`
`style={styles.btn}`
`onPress={() => {`
`LogInHandler();`
 `}}`
`>`
`<AntDesign name="google" size={24} color="white" />`
`<Text style={styles.txt}> Continue with Google</Text>`
`</TouchableOpacity>`
`</View>`
`);`
`}`

`const styles = StyleSheet.create({`
 `container: {`
 `flex: 1,`
 `justifyContent: "center",`
 `alignItems: "center",`
 `},`
 `btn: {`
 `flexDirection: "row",`
 `width: 200,`
 `borderRadius: 10,`
 `backgroundColor: "#516BEB",`
 `justifyContent: "center",`
 `padding: 10,`
 `alignItems: "center",`
 `},`
 `txt: {`
 `color: "white",`
 `fontWeight: "bold",`
 `},`
 `header: {`
 `fontWeight: "bold",`
 `fontSize: 30,`
 `marginBottom: 50,`
 `},`
 ``` });``<br> ```
`

Answer (score 0):

This library seems to be deprecated. Take a look [here](https://github.com/expo/expo-google-app-auth)